# Changing Phys mat in unity when contact with a different collider tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and got stuck need help.
Im trying to make a small game involving trampolines and i used a script to send the character with force but i dont want the character to bounce normally when on the trampoline because they might go to high, but still bounce around on normal non- trampoline ground.
I have 2 Phys mats set up i just dont know how to switch them. when on different ground

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhysMatChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log(collisionInfo.collider.name);
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "trampup") ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Evan. What exactly is your question and how does the code snippet relate to that? Help people to understand your problem by being as precise as possible. It sometimes helps yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the physics material of a collider col:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-material.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PhysicMaterial.html

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhysMatChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PhysicsMaterial materialOne; 
    public PhysicsMaterial materialTwo; 
    private Collider col;

    private void Start()
    {
        col = GetComponent<Collider>(); 
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log(collisionInfo.collider.name);
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "trampup")
        {
            // change to the first material
            col.material = materialOne; 
        }
        else if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "trampdown")
        {
            // change to second material
            col.material = materialTwo; 
        }
    }
}
```

You can configure the bounciness of a physics material in the inspector